# Sort an array except one element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array and I am sorting it but I need to sort everything except one element of my array.

My array is:

```
var Comparison = [
    {key: "None", value: "None"},
    {key:"Geographical Area", value:"Geographical_Area"},
    {key:"Forests", value:"Forests"},
    {key:"Barren Unculturable Land", value:"Barren_Unculturable_Land"},
    {key:"Land put to Non agricultural use", value:"Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use"},
    {key:"Land Area", value:"Land_Area"},
    {key:"Water Area", value:"Water_Area"},
    {key:"Culturable Waste", value:"Culturable_Waste"},
    {key:"Permanent Pastures", value:"Permanent_Pastures"},
    {key:"Land under Tree Crops", value:"Land_under_Tree_Crops"},
    {key:"Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value:"Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow"},
    {key:"Current Fallow", value:"Current_Fallow"},
    {key:"Total Unculturable Land", value:"Total_Unculturable_Land"},
    {key:"Net Sown Area", value:"Net_Sown_Area"},
    {key:"Gross Sown Area", value:"Gross_Sown_Area"},
    {key:"Cropping Intensity", value:"Cropping_Intensity"} ];
```

I am sorting this array using this code:

```
var Comparison_sort = this.Comparison.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.key < b.key)
      return -1;
  if (a.key > b.key)
      return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

This is sorting my array perfectly, but I want one of my elements to be on top, meaning my element None should be on top and sort all other elements.

For example, I am getting this result:

```
   {key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land"}
   {key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity"}
   {key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste"}
    ....
   {key: "None", value: "None"}
```

But I want a result like this:

```
   {key: "None", value: "None"}
   {key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land"}
   {key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity"}
   {key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste"}
    ....
```

I saw an answer, *[Sort array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491071/sort-an-array-except-one-item-using-typescript)*, but I was unable to use this answer to my problem.

Comment: Just check if the key is none, return the sort value of object containing that key as -1 ?

Comment: treat it a special value. filter it off your array, sort it, put it back where you want it. Or check for it in the compare function, making sure it is always "less than the others" (as KarelG suggested)

Comment: @DaveNewton do you mean if there is one `None` in the array somewhere else than first position, or do you mean if there are several `None` in the array ?

Comment: @DaveNewton if there is no `"none"` in the collection, then the branch `if (a.key === "none") { return -1}` is never executed ... If placed first.

Comment: @DaveNewton no. not irrelevant. Do not over-complicate things.

Comment: @DaveNewton But, if it's greater than any object it is compared too, how could it *not* be sorted as the top element ? Can you provide a working counter example ?

Comment: `a` may never see the ‘none’ element (it may be passed to the sort function only as `b`)

Comment: @DaveNewton I just did what you suggest, None gets in first position.

Comment: @DaveNewton : with solution checking for a and b values *first*, of course,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557233/479251

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand your point now. With spi's answer, it's working fine though.

Comment: @Pac0 Totally my bad; I was using a broken compare.

Comment: @DaveNewton https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557538/2412895

Comment: Don't forget about [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). You're making it harder than it is to begin with.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
var Comparison_sort = this.Comparison.sort(function (a, b) {
  if(a.key == b.key) return 0;
  if (a.key == 'None') return -1;
  if (b.key == 'None') return 1;

  if (a.key < b.key)
      return -1;
  if (a.key > b.key)
      return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

tells "do a regular sort, except if the key is none which means it must go first."

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you can filter out the nones and sort the other elements. Then concatenate them back to each other at the end.

```js
const comparison = [{key: "None", value: "None"}, {key: "Geographical Area", value: "Geographical_Area"}, {key: "Forests", value: "Forests"}, {key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Land put to Non agricultural use", value: "Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use"}, {key: "Land Area", value: "Land_Area"}, {key: "Water Area", value: "Water_Area"}, {key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste"}, {key: "Permanent Pastures", value: "Permanent_Pastures"}, {key: "Land under Tree Crops", value: "Land_under_Tree_Crops"}, {key: "Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value: "Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Current Fallow", value: "Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Total Unculturable Land", value: "Total_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Net Sown Area", value: "Net_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Gross Sown Area", value: "Gross_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity"}];

const result = comparison
  .filter(e => e.key === 'None')
  .concat(
    comparison
      .filter(e => e.key !== 'None')
      .sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key))
  );
               
console.log(result);
```

Explanation:

```js
const comparison = [{key: "None", value: "None"}, {key: "Geographical Area", value: "Geographical_Area"}, {key: "Forests", value: "Forests"}, {key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Land put to Non agricultural use", value: "Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use"}, {key: "Land Area", value: "Land_Area"}, {key: "Water Area", value: "Water_Area"}, {key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste"}, {key: "Permanent Pastures", value: "Permanent_Pastures"}, {key: "Land under Tree Crops", value: "Land_under_Tree_Crops"}, {key: "Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value: "Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Current Fallow", value: "Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Total Unculturable Land", value: "Total_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Net Sown Area", value: "Net_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Gross Sown Area", value: "Gross_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity"}];

// get all elements with the key 'None'
const nones = comparison.filter(e => e.key === 'None');
// get all elements with the key not 'None'
const others = comparison.filter(e => e.key !== 'None')
// sort the elements in the array by key
others.sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key));
// concatenate the 2 arrays together
const result = nones.concat(others);

console.log(result);
```

A bit of credit to [Pac0s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557367/3982562). After writing my solution I saw that I basically made a working version of his explanation. I'm too late to add my example to his answer because this is currently the most upvoted of the two.

---

For larger arrays using `filter()` two times on the same array with the opposite predicate (check callback) might be a bit inefficient. You could opt to introduce a helper function like `partition()` to help reduce the amount of iteration that has to be done.

```js
function partition(forEachable, callback) {
  const partitions = { "true": [], "false": [] };
  forEachable.forEach((...args) => partitions[!!callback(...args)].push(args[0]));
  return [partitions[true], partitions[false]];
}

let comparison = [{key: "None", value: "None"}, {key: "Geographical Area", value: "Geographical_Area"}, {key: "Forests", value: "Forests"}, {key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Land put to Non agricultural use", value: "Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use"}, {key: "Land Area", value: "Land_Area"}, {key: "Water Area", value: "Water_Area"}, {key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste"}, {key: "Permanent Pastures", value: "Permanent_Pastures"}, {key: "Land under Tree Crops", value: "Land_under_Tree_Crops"}, {key: "Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value: "Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Current Fallow", value: "Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Total Unculturable Land", value: "Total_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Net Sown Area", value: "Net_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Gross Sown Area", value: "Gross_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity"}];

const [nones, others] = partition(comparison, e => e.key === "None");
others.sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key));
const result = nones.concat(others);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 10):

Not fancy, but a pretty straightforward way of doing this is to just remove the special element, sort the array, and insert the special to whatever index you want.

```js
var Comparison = [{ key: "None", value: "None" }, { key: "Geographical Area",value: "Geographical_Area" }, { key: "Forests", value: "Forests" }, { key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land" }, { key: "Land put to Non agricultural use", value: "Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use" }, { key: "Land Area", value: "Land_Area" }, { key: "Water Area", value: "Water_Area" }, { key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste" }, { key: "Permanent Pastures", value: "Permanent_Pastures" }, { key: "Land under Tree Crops", value: "Land_under_Tree_Crops" }, { key: "Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value: "Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow" }, { key: "Current Fallow", value: "Current_Fallow" }, { key: "Total Unculturable Land", value: "Total_Unculturable_Land" }, { key: "Net Sown Area", value: "Net_Sown_Area" }, { key: "Gross Sown Area", value: "Gross_Sown_Area" }, { key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity" },];

const idx = Comparison.findIndex(a => a.key === 'None');
const none = Comparison.splice(idx, 1);
Comparison.sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key));
Comparison.splice(0,0, none[0]);

console.log(Comparison);
```

**To avoid no special or multiple special element issues:**

```js
var Comparison = [{ key: "None", value: "None" }, { key: "Geographical Area",value: "Geographical_Area" }, { key: "Forests", value: "Forests" }, { key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land" }, { key: "Land put to Non agricultural use", value: "Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use" }, { key: "Land Area", value: "Land_Area" }, { key: "Water Area", value: "Water_Area" }, { key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste" }, { key: "Permanent Pastures", value: "Permanent_Pastures" }, { key: "Land under Tree Crops", value: "Land_under_Tree_Crops" }, { key: "Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value: "Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow" }, { key: "Current Fallow", value: "Current_Fallow" }, { key: "Total Unculturable Land", value: "Total_Unculturable_Land" }, { key: "Net Sown Area", value: "Net_Sown_Area" }, { key: "Gross Sown Area", value: "Gross_Sown_Area" }, { key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity" },];

const obj = Comparison.reduce((acc, a) => {
  if (a.key === 'None') {
    acc.f.push(a);
  } else {
    const idx = acc.s.findIndex(b => b.key.localeCompare(a.key) > 0);
    acc.s.splice(idx === -1 ? acc.s.length : idx, 0, a);
  }
  return acc;
}, { f: [], s: [] });

const res = obj.f.concat(obj.s);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks @JohanWentholt

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that doesn't work with a missing element `'None'`, or multiple elements `'None'`. In the case of no element `'None'` `findIndex` will return `-1` and `.splice(-1, 1)` will chop of the last element and place it back at the front. In the case of multiple elements only the first element `'None'` is placed back in the first position. But for exactly one element this is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: Yes that's totally right, but I just thought that's not the case here

Comment: I agree with you that it's a fine solution. The above is just a warning for readers who stumble upon the question and don't fully got the context of the question.

Answer (score 7):

There might be a better approach, but this should work:

1. Filter the special value out of your array.
2. Sort your array without the special value.
3. Insert the special value back in the array.

For a good working example, see [@Johan Wentholt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51558338/479251)!

Comment: unnecessarily complex. needs 2 arrays creation (reduction/expansion)

Comment: @spi I certainly prefer your answer better too, the comment discussion that was ongoing putme in doubt, I wanted to provide another answer that was correct without falling into the discussed cases. While I understand this is not the *best answer*, and for some persons not worthy of an upvote, I'm not sure my answer deserves a downvote either.

Comment: if you edit I'd remove the downvote, but indeed does not deserve an upvote :)

Comment: @Pac0 I just see that my answer is the same as yours, shall I add my running JavaScript example under your answer? (Since you answered first.) Your explanation is also more clear.

Comment: @JohanWentholt not sure if the complexity we are talking creates any overhead at runtime (in opposition with the creation of 2 useless arrays). All those ifs are the original code of the OP + the fix using the same coding style. But I agree the OP should use a function like localCompare to avoid reimplementing the wheel.

Comment: @JohanWentholt You can incorporate an implementation in my answer, with pleasure, thank you very much. I was (and am not) currently with a correct setup and environment to write one.

Comment: @JohanWentholt  I just saw you actually had your answer already much upvoted ! You should keep your answer and you can copy my explanations into it if you feel it's useful.

Comment: @Pac0 I think I might just leave it as is at this point, because that's what got it the upvotes in the first place.

Comment: The best answer ) I would the same

Answer (score 5):

A simple one-liner: if any of the keys in [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Sort) compare function is 'None', then always put it on top, otherwise do basic comparison of keys with [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
var comparison = [{key: "None", value: "None"}, {key: "Geographical Area", value: "Geographical_Area"}, {key: "Forests", value: "Forests"}, {key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Land put to Non agricultural use", value: "Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use"}, {key: "Land Area", value: "Land_Area"}, {key: "Water Area", value: "Water_Area"}, {key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste"}, {key: "Permanent Pastures", value: "Permanent_Pastures"}, {key: "Land under Tree Crops", value: "Land_under_Tree_Crops"}, {key: "Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value: "Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Current Fallow", value: "Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Total Unculturable Land", value: "Total_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Net Sown Area", value: "Net_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Gross Sown Area", value: "Gross_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity"}];

var sorted = comparison.sort((a,b) => a.key === 'None' ? -1 : b.key === 'None' ? 1 : a.key.localeCompare(b.key));

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` to achieve the desired output:

```js
var Comparison = [{key:"Geographical Area", value:"Geographical_Area"},   {key:"Forests", value:"Forests"},   {key:"Barren Unculturable Land", value:"Barren_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "None", value: "None"},  {key:"Land put to Non agricultural use", value:"Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use"}, {key:"Land Area", value:"Land_Area"},   {key:"Water Area", value:"Water_Area"}, {key:"Culturable Waste", value:"Culturable_Waste"}, {key:"Permanent Pastures", value:"Permanent_Pastures"}, {key:"Land under Tree Crops", value:"Land_under_Tree_Crops"},   {key:"Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value:"Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow"},   {key:"Current Fallow", value:"Current_Fallow"}, {key:"Total Unculturable Land", value:"Total_Unculturable_Land"},   {key:"Net Sown Area", value:"Net_Sown_Area"},   {key:"Gross Sown Area", value:"Gross_Sown_Area"},   {key:"Cropping Intensity", value:"Cropping_Intensity"},]

var Comparison_sort = Comparison
                      .sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key))
                      .reduce((acc, e) => {
                        e.key === 'None' ? acc.unshift(e) : acc.push(e);
                        return acc;
                      }, []);

console.log(Comparison_sort);
```

Sort using `reduce` version-2:

```js
let comparison = [{key: "None", value: "None"}, {key: "Geographical Area", value: "Geographical_Area"}, {key: "Forests", value: "Forests"}, {key: "Barren Unculturable Land", value: "Barren_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Land put to Non agricultural use", value: "Land_put_to_Non_agricultural_use"}, {key: "Land Area", value: "Land_Area"}, {key: "Water Area", value: "Water_Area"}, {key: "Culturable Waste", value: "Culturable_Waste"}, {key: "Permanent Pastures", value: "Permanent_Pastures"}, {key: "Land under Tree Crops", value: "Land_under_Tree_Crops"}, {key: "Fallow Land excl Current Fallow", value: "Fallow_Land_excl_Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Current Fallow", value: "Current_Fallow"}, {key: "Total Unculturable Land", value: "Total_Unculturable_Land"}, {key: "Net Sown Area", value: "Net_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Gross Sown Area", value: "Gross_Sown_Area"}, {key: "Cropping Intensity", value: "Cropping_Intensity"}];

var {Comparison_sort} = comparison.reduce((acc, obj, idx, arr) => {
                                  obj.key === 'None' ? acc['first'].push(obj) : acc['last'].push(obj)
                                  if (idx === arr.length - 1) (acc['last'].sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key)), acc['Comparison_sort'] = [...acc['first'], ...acc['last']])
                                  return acc
                                }, {first: [], last: [], Comparison_sort: []})

console.log(Comparison_sort);
```

Comment: over engineering.

Comment: Yeah, but... that seems extravagant.

Comment: Your solution was quite nice using `reduce`. After the change it's basically the same as spis answer. Mind if I clean it up a bit and and change the logic back to use `reduce`? (Since that's what differentiates this answer from others.)

Answer (score 3):

The `<Array>.sort` function takes a callback as an argument. This callback will be passed two values. The job of the callback is to determine which one is bigger. It does this by returning a numeric value.

Let's say the arguments passed to your callback are called `a` and `b`. I have bolded the values your callback should return for each case

- `a < b` **Less than 0**
- `a > b` **Greater than 0**
- `a = b` **Equal to 0**

This is easy to remember because, for numerical values, you can use `a - b` to get a desired return value.

Now, despite most callbacks passed to `.sort` are very small, it *is* possible to pass in very complicated functions to suit your need. In this case,

- If `a.key` is None, **`a < b`**
- If `b.key` is None, **`b < a`**
- Else, use our current sort mechanism.

We could take advantage of the `return` statement exiting once it's called. So, let's implement this function bullet-by-bullet.

To make our code Super Good, let's return "0" when the two values are equal (even when those two values have keys of "None")

```
Comparison.sort(function(a, b) {
  // Our extra code
  if(a.key === b.key) return 0; // Zero (a = b)
  if(a.key === "None") return -1; // Negative (a < b)
  if(b.key === "None") return 1; // Positive (b < a)

  // Old sort
  if(a.key < b.key) return -1;
  if(b.key < a.key) return 1;  
})
```

## Golfing that solution

There are ways to make that solution shorter (and, perhaps, more readable) -- which is important when code is doing simple tasks.

The first thing to note is that the final line, `if(b.key < a.key) return -1` could be shortened to `return -1;`. This is because if `a.key < b.key` or `b.key = a.key` we would've returned on an earlier line.

The second thing to note is that using ES6 syntax (which might not be compatible with older browsers, particularly regarding Internet Explorer), we can use arrow function notation for the callback.

`function(a, b) {}` could become `(a, b) => {}`

The third thing to note is that we can convert the below block of code

```
if(a.key < b.key) return -1;
if(b.key < a.key) return 1;
```

into

```
return (b.key < a.key) - (a.key < b.key)
```

That's because `true` is treated as `1`, and `false` as `0` when regarding subtraction. `true - false` is `1 - 0` is `1`, `false - true` is `0 - 1` is `-1`, and `0 - 0` is `0`. There will never be a situation where `true - true` occurs.

Comment: `return (b.key < a.key) - 0.5` does not return 0 for identical key values. `return (b.key < a.key) - (a.key < b.key);` returns -1, 0, 1 as expected by Array#sort.

Answer (score 2):

short and sweet!

```
   var Comparison_sort = this.Comparison.sort((a, b) => (a.key == b.key) ? 0 : (a.key == 'None') ? -1 : (b.key == 'None') ? 1 : (a.key > b.key ) ? 1 : -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check at the beginning. If it's the none object then move it to the front without performing the checks.

```
var Comparison_sort = this.Comparison.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.key == "None" && a.value == "None")
        return -1;
    if (b.key == "None" && b.value == "None")
        return 1;
    if (a.key < b.key)
            return -1;
    if (a.key > b.key)
            return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: This won't work in the general case, e.g., `None` appears elsewhere in the list.

Comment: @DaveNewton all elements in the array will eventually be passed into the sort function as a or b, I don’t see how it misses any.

Comment: Comparing an item to itself must return 0 otherwise your sort might not be stable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it positioned **at the top** you could just **return -1** or you could **return 1** if you want your item **at the bottom** of the list.

You do not need multiple if's for the firstly or lastly positioned item which you want to exclude from the general sort.

```
this.Comparison.sort(function (a, b) {
  if(a.key == b.key) return 0;
  if (a.key == 'None' || b.key == 'None') return -1;

  if (a.key < b.key)
      return -1;
  if (a.key > b.key)
      return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array1 = this.Comparison.filter(e => e.key === 'None');
const array2 = this.Comparison
            .filter(e => e.key !== 'None')
            .sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key));

this.Comparison = [].concat(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Your answer should include some comments about your approach. See [Answer].

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great if you only have one item that is to be put on the top of the list, but what if the list needs multiple items put at the start?

The below code takes an array of items in a particular order and makes sure they are always first in the sorted array.

```
var items = ["P", "Third", "First", "D", "A", "Z", "Second", "Fourth"];
var topItems = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"];
//var topItemsObj = { First: 1, Second: 2, Third: 3, Fourth: 4 };

var mySortFunc = function (a, b) {
    // Add 1 because normally -1 is not found & !0 == true.
    // This could also be replaced by object as !undefined == true. See commented code.
    var 
        isFirstItem = (v) => topItems.indexOf(v) + 1, 
        //isFirstItem = (v) => topItemsObj[v] || 0,
        t1 = isFirstItem(a),
        t2 = isFirstItem(b);


    if (t1 && t2) return t1 - t2; // Both items are first items. Sort by array index
    if (t1 || t2) return t2 - t1; // One item is first item. Prioritise first item
    return a.localeCompare(b); // Both items are not first items. Sort normally
}

items.sort(mySortFunc)
//  ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'A', 'D', 'P', 'Z']
```